# how to create action button react native redirect other page?

Tags: react-native, action-button

i'm new in react native. i'm use react native action button and i want if button clicked, then show other page. this is my code but still doesn't work. have any solution?

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={() => this.buttonPressed}>
          </ActionButton>
        </View>
    );
  }

 buttonPressed() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NewCase', {});
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't execute **buttonPressed** at all. Fix it with `()`:

`<ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={() => this.buttonPressed()}>`

Other way would be:

`<ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={this.buttonPressed.bind(this)}>`

And like said in the comments, you should ensure that **navigation** actually exists in the props.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to pass the navigation prop to the component

Comment: can you make example for this?. thanks for reply. :-) @David Vittori

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
<ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={() => this.buttonPressed('page2')}>

buttonPressed(page){
  this.props.navigator.replace({
    id: page,
  })
}
```

You just put buttonPressed thats doesn't really do nothing if you have a buttonPressed() to exec the transition you need to put buttonPressed() , by the away a good thing to do is putting this type of function with '_' behind , like this: _buttonPressed('page2') and then _buttonPressed(page) , it helps a bit to know what you are doing